# C# Irony Parser - Won't parse file despite everything seems correct

Tags: c#, parsing, irony

I am having some tricky problems with Irony which I do not understand...

The first parsing I do in the runtime of my application succeeds.

```
string src = "" // this is the file to parse
Grammar g = new CSharpGrammar();
LanguageData language = new LanguageData(g);
Parser parser = new Parser(language);
ParseTree parseTree = parser.Parse(src);
ParseRoot = parseTree.Root;
```

Then I followed one hint to move the LanguageData variable to the global context. Still everything ok. But now I wanted to call the Irony parser inside of custom functions, parsing multiple files with the c# grammar v3.5 provided by Irony (LINQ queries are not important to me, so that seems sufficient). Same approach:

```
Parser parser = new Parser(language);
ParseTree parseTree = parser.Parse(file);
ParseRoot = parseTree.Root;
```

But now the parseroot is and remains "null". And I have absolutely no idea why. I also checked the parser errors a moment ago, there I recognized an error I cannot comprehend.

```
"Syntax error, expected: statement, member declaration, namespace"
```

But my file looks like this:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls;

namespace WebParts.Layouts.Ordering
{
    public partial class ConfirmDelete : LayoutsPageBase
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblMsg.Text = "Are you sure you want to delete the entry?";

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                BtnYes.Attributes.Add("onclick", "OnYes(); return false;");
                BtnNo.Attributes.Add("onclick", "OnNo(); return false;");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope you can see what's wrong with my code... I'm getting desperate with this thing...

Comment: This would be enlightening to know the purpose you want to achieve when parsing c#, could you please tell us?

Comment: "Then I followed one hint to move the LanguageData variable to the global context." More explanation on that please.

Comment: the purpose is to write the code structure of a project (namespaces, classes, methods, properties, members) to a sql database for further debugging purposes.

Comment: with "moving to global context" i mean that i do not initialize the grammar and languagedata variables each time i use the parser...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide a filename as the second argument of parser.Parse:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Grammar g = new CSharpGrammar();
    LanguageData language = new LanguageData(g);
    Parser parser = new Parser(language);
    ParseTree parseTree = parser.Parse("", "class1.cs");

    var r = parseTree.Root;
}
```